# best options for a detailed azure invoice?

Tags: azure

I need to provide a detailed invoice for Azure usage to a client.  I'd like to be able to provide as granular of a breakdown as possible.  For example, if an Azure cost of $10 was accrued for an App Service on one day, then I'd like to be able to provide the info on why that was, if that info is available.  Was the cost due to a distributed allocation of a monthly cost?  Was the cost due to a specific measure of ingress/egress?  etc.  This is my first time trying to provide a detailed invoice like this, so I'm sure that there are others here who have had the need to do this before who can probably provide some valuable insight on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the cost breakdown under [`Cost Management`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/cost-analysis-common-uses) in Azure Portal

In the Azure portal, navigate to cost analysis for your scope. For example: `Cost Management + Billing > Cost Management > Cost analysis.`
Select Cost by resource.
Change the view to Table.